# How can I use Sympy equation in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, sympy

I plotted a graph using matplotlib. How can I use sympy equation as the label of the legend?

Let's assume I have this math expression:
[Eq](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsXXU.png)

How can I show this math expression in the legend of a graph in matplotlib?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [`sympy.latex`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/printing.html#mathrm-latex) ? Because Matplotlib supports [*writing mathematical expressions*](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/mathtext.html).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy import Eq, latex, symbols

eq = sympy.latex(Eq(symbols("beta"), 0.9))

x, y = [1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6]

plt.plot(x, y, label=f"${eq}$")

plt.legend()

plt.show();
```

Output :

[image]